# Using the squeeze principle to evaluate the following limit

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

[image]

This is my teacher's work. I am stuck on the part where I circled it red. From what I understand, he squared every side, so (-1)^2, the cos^2, and the 1^2. Why did (-1)^2 change to 0?

Comment: $cos^2(3x+1)$ is non-negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the $-1$ did not turn into $0$, the inequality $0\leq \cos^2 (3x+1)$ comes from the fact that $x^2\geq0$ if $x$ is a real number.

The statement $0\leq \cos^2(3x+1) \leq 1$ is actually composed of two inequalities. One, $\cos^2(3x+1)\leq 1$, comes from the fact that $\cos(3x+1)$ is between $-1$ and $1$. The other, $\cos^2(3x+1)\geq 0$, comes from the fact that $\cos^2(3x+1)$ is the square of a real number, and squares of all real numbers are non-negative.

Comment: i still don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @Kaaagome How about now?

Comment: @bof Fixed it, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Exercise: Let $a\geqslant0$ and $b\geqslant0$, then the following equivalences hold.

- $a\leqslant x\leqslant b\iff a^2\leqslant x^2\leqslant b^2$
- $-a\leqslant x\leqslant b\iff 0\leqslant x^2\leqslant\max(a,b)^2$

Hint: Plot a graph of the function $x\mapsto x^2$, say on the interval $[-4,3]$.

Comment: Sweet downvoters...

Comment: Let me even that out for you .. Edit: Ahh, I'm at my vote limit, never mind.

Comment: I think the downvoter only read the first part of your question, where it seems as though you only stated your two bullet points qwithout explaining them. I don't think this answer deserves a downvote.

Comment: It's the most reasonable answer to be honest.

Comment: @ChantryCargill Thanks but please do not upvote to compensate other votes. (You know, that this answer is downvoted, being clearly absurd to anyone reading it (I think), is actually *useful* if it makes people think about the meaning of votes on the site.)

Comment: @5xum Charitable conjecture: every answer on the page received two downvotes because two users think the question should not be answered, and none of them knows how to "close" a question, and only one of the pair thought about downvoting the question itself. Hmmm... Not sure that this explanation holds water, after all. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\cos(a) = 0$ when $a = \frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Thus, $\cos^2(a) = 0$. What does this say about the interval in question?

Another way to look at it is that the cosine function can evaluate to any value in $[-1,0] \cup [0,1]$. So when we square it, it becomes $[0,1]$.

What values are between $-1$ and $1$? Well, there's $-0.9$, which squares is $0.81$. There's $-0.5$, which squares is $0.25$. If we keep going we eventually get to $0$, which squared is still $0$. Then we have all the values from $0$ to $1$.

So as you can see, the interval becomes $[0,1]$. No matter how you look at it.